# How to solve java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, user-interface

Here is my code:

```
    try {
        scan_movie_theater = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("d:/movietheater.txt")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


    while((line = scan_movie_theater.next()) != null ){                 
        i = scan_movie_theater.nextInt();
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(i);          
    }
    scan_movie_theater.close();
```

I want to read the file like one string one integer. And i can do this. But when i finished the read of the file. I see a java java.util.NoSuchElementException. How can i fix this?

And this is my txt file.

```
dsa 435
salon 123
xxxx 123214324
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
    while( scan_movie_theater.hasNext()){
        line = scan_movie_theater.next();
        i = scan_movie_theater.nextInt();
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(i);          
    }
```

In your current implementation you are trying to read past the end.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

See the Javadoc. Scanner.next() doesn't return null. You have to check hasNext() before calling next().

95% of your code isn't relevant to the question, including ***all*** the Swing code.

Comment: The idea is to do something about it, for future readers. I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when you are trying to access elements after the end of the collection. i.e. elements which are actually not present because the list has been already ended.
Solution:You have to check EOF and also hasNext().
next() just moves the cursor to the next element and you are trying to access an element which is not present after the EOF.
So, try using hasNext(), which checkes for the presence of next element and then apply next() to retrieve the next element.

Comment: You don't 'have to check EOF and also hasNext()'. They are the same thing.

Comment: @EJP: either of the 2 you may choose for your code to check for a good program.